# How to empty recycling bin in batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-7, recycle-bin

I need a code to empty the recycling bin without conformation I have tried the simple `del $Recycle.Bin` but it says access denied even when elevated does any one know a code I could use.

Comment: This command does it for me: powershell.exe Clear-RecycleBin -force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This emptied my bin without any confirmation.

```
@ECHO OFF
start /b /wait powershell.exe -command "$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application;$RecycleBin = $Shell.Namespace(0xA);$RecycleBin.Items() | foreach{Remove-Item $_.Path -Recurse -Confirm:$false}"
```

Comment: but maybe is permissions issue if this fails.   Are you trying to delete your own recycle bin or one owned by another user ?

Comment: All of them from all accounts

Comment: I have tried it and it says $Shell is not a valid program or command

Comment: forgot to add the start wrapper to run powershell from batch.

Comment: The powershell command doesn't empty the recycle bin through a system command, but just deletes the files individually, right?

Comment: Yep, it loops through them one by one.

Comment: `C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-blah\$R4JAJOK.pdf: You do not have
    sufficient access rights to perform this operation.`  <-- I get this error on 4 files with a `read only` attribute.   There are a whole load of files left in the folder which are all 544 bytes in size - JPG DOC TXT etc.

Comment: Can you delete it after taking ownership ?

Comment: I just saw your reply (no @foxidrive there).  If a script has to take ownership then it would also need admin permissions, but it was just the read-only attribute that was different.  I'm not sure what the 544 byte files were designed to do - the binary content looked like a link to a folder.

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are ok for cmd batch files but for the new powershell there is a [better way](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/08/04/powertip-use-powershell-5-to-clear-recycle-bin/)

Simply use the cmdlet

`Clear-RecycleBin`

Optionally you can use the  **-Force** or **-Confirm:$false** parameters so it won't ask for confirmation

For more info open powershell and type

`Get-Help Clear-RecycleBin`

Answer (score 1):

I have just found this.

```
erase /s/q/f "C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\*">nul
```

Answer (score 1):

Guaranteed to delete all content in the Recycle Bin for the selected drive while leaving the folder itself intact:

```
C:\$Recycle Bin\>rd . /q /s
```

- Change to the required drive
- Change into the `$Recycle Bin` folder
- Run the command `rd . /q /s` [remove-dir (currentdir) /quiet /subdir]

You will get an error that the current directory is still in use (because that is your current location) and can't be deleted. This is expected behaviour because I want the `$Recycle Bin` folder to remain.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the `/s` parameter had to come before the `/q`:
`rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.Bin` should be the command to run and empty recycle bin from a batch file, right?

Comment: actually, it makes no difference whether you use `rd /s /q` or `rd /q /s`